# How to limit the scaledown of an svg not less than its original size?

Tags: jquery, svg

HTML

```
<button class="zoom_plus">+</button>
<button class="zoom_minus">-</button>
<div class="map" data-scale="0">
   <svg>...</svg>
</div>
```

JS scaledown (how not to scale less than its original size?) :

```
var $map = $(".map");
$(".zoom_minus").on("click", function(){
    var $svg = $map.find('svg');
    var current_scale = $map.attr('data-scale');
        current_scale = parseInt(current_scale,10);
    var sclae_to = current_scale - 2;

    $svg.css({'transform': 'scale('+ sclae_to +')'});
    $map.attr('data-scale',sclae_to);
});
```

JS scale UP

```
$(".zoom_plus").on("click", function(){
    var $svg = $map.find('svg');
    var current_scale = $map.attr('data-scale');
        current_scale = parseInt(current_scale,10);
    var sclae_to = current_scale + 2;

    $svg.css({'transform': 'scale('+ sclae_to +')'});
    $map.attr('data-scale',sclae_to);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the initial value of data-scale and use scaleDown conditionally:

```
var $map = $(".map");
var initialScale=parseInt($map.attr('data-scale'));

$(".zoom_plus").on("click", function(){
    var $svg = $map.find('svg');
    var current_scale = $map.attr('data-scale');
        current_scale = parseInt(current_scale,10);
    var sclae_to = current_scale - 2;

    //Perform this check
    if(sclae_to<initialScale){sclae_to=initialScale;}

    $svg.css({'transform': 'scale('+ sclae_to +')'});
    $map.attr('data-scale',sclae_to);
});
```

Besides it not seems correct to define two onClick functions both on map!

Comment: moved var $map = $(this); our of the click as it is a button and said var $map = $(".map");

Comment: in Ediited version you are still using $(this)

Comment: you are correct, thanks for pointing that out. Updated, applied your code but no luck still

Comment: Did you set initial `data-scale=100` or any else  for map?

Comment: well no, didn't know i had to, you haven't provided that